# ValueError: Compute method failed to assign

Tags: python, odoo

```
Error:
    Odoo Server Error
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
        result = request.dispatch()
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 684, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 360, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 348, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 913, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 532, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "d:\odoo-14.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1347, in search_read
        return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
      File "d:\odoo-14.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1366, in do_search_read
        return Model.web_search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=sort)
      File "d:\odoo-14.0\addons\web\models\models.py", line 62, in web_search_read
        records = self.search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 4841, in search_read
        result = records.read(fields)
      File "d:\odoo-14.0\custom\muk_dms_attachment\models\file.py", line 138, in read
        return super(File, self).read(fields, load=load)
      File "d:\odoo-14.0\custom\muk_dms\models\file.py", line 398, in read
        return super(File, self).read(fields, load=load)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 3022, in read
        return self._read_format(fnames=fields, load=load)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 3042, in _read_format
        vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 5668, in __getitem__
        return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\fields.py", line 2483, in __get__
        return super().__get__(records, owner)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\fields.py", line 1026, in __get__
        raise ValueError("Compute method failed to assign %s.%s" % (record, self.name))
    Exception
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "D:\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
        raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
    ValueError: Compute method failed to assign muk_dms.file(1,).actions
    
    
    here is my code:
    ###################################################################################
    #
    #    Copyright (c) 2017-2019 MuK IT GmbH.
    #
    #    This file is part of MuK Documents
    #    (see https://mukit.at).
    #
    #    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    #    it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
    #    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    #    (at your option) any later version.
    #
    #    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    #    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    #    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    #    GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
    #
    #    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
    #    along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
    #
    ###################################################################################
    
    import os
    import io
    import json
    import base64
    import logging
    import mimetypes
    import itertools
    import tempfile
    import hashlib
    import operator
    import functools
    
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    from odoo import _, SUPERUSER_ID
    from odoo import models, api, fields, tools
    from odoo.tools.mimetypes import guess_mimetype
    from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError
    from odoo.exceptions import AccessError
    from odoo.osv import expression
    
    from . import file
    from odoo.addons.muk_security.tools.security import NoSecurityUid
    
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    class File(models.Model):
    
        _name = 'muk_dms.file'
        _description = "File"
    
        _inherit = [
             'muk_security.mixins.access_rights',
             'muk_security.mixins.locking',
             'muk_dms.mixins.thumbnail',
        ]
    
        _order = "name asc"
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Database
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        name = fields.Char(
            string="Filename",
            required=True,
            index=True)
        locked_by = fields.Char()
        is_locked = fields.Char()
        is_lock_editor = fields.Char()
        permission_write = fields.Char()
        permission_unlink = fields.Char()
    
    
        active = fields.Boolean(
            string="Archived",
            default=True,
            help="If a file is set to archived, it is not displayed, but still exists.")
    
        directory = fields.Many2one(
            comodel_name='muk_dms.directory',
            string="Directory",
            domain="[('permission_create', '=', True)]",
            context="{'dms_directory_show_path': True}",
            ondelete='restrict',
            auto_join=True,
            required=True,
            index=True)
    
        storage = fields.Many2one(
            related="directory.storage",
            comodel_name='muk_dms.storage',
            string="Storage",
            auto_join=True,
            readonly=True,
            store=True)
    
        is_hidden = fields.Boolean(
            string="Storage is Hidden",
            related="storage.is_hidden",
            readonly=True)
    
        company = fields.Many2one(
            related="storage.company",
            comodel_name='res.company',
            string='Company',
            readonly=True,
            store=True,
            index=True)
    
        path_names = fields.Char(
            compute='_compute_path',
            string="Path Names",
            readonly=True,
            store=False)
    
        path_json = fields.Text(
            compute='_compute_path',
            string="Path Json",
            readonly=True,
            store=False)
    
        color = fields.Integer(
            string="Color",
            default=0)
    
        category = fields.Many2one(
            comodel_name='muk_dms.category',
            context="{'dms_category_show_path': True}",
            string="Category")
    
        tags = fields.Many2many(
            comodel_name='muk_dms.tag',
            relation='muk_dms_file_tag_rel',
            column1='fid',
            column2='tid',
            string='Tags')
    
        content = fields.Binary(
            compute='_compute_content',
            inverse='_inverse_content',
            string='Content',
            attachment=False,
            prefetch=False,
            required=True,
            store=False)
    
        extension = fields.Char(
            compute='_compute_extension',
            string='Extension',
            readonly=True,
            store=True)
    
        mimetype = fields.Char(
            compute='_compute_mimetype',
            string='Type',
            readonly=True,
            store=True)
    
        size = fields.Integer(
            string='Size',
            readonly=True)
    
        checksum = fields.Char(
            string="Checksum/SHA1",
            readonly=True,
            size=40,
            index=True)
    
        content_binary = fields.Binary(
            string="Content Binary",
            attachment=False,
            prefetch=False,
            invisible=True)
    
        save_type = fields.Char(
            compute='_compute_save_type',
            string='Current Save Type',
            invisible=True,
            prefetch=False)
    
        migration = fields.Char(
            compute='_compute_migration',
            string='Migration Status',
            readonly=True,
            prefetch=False)
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Helper
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.model
        def _get_checksum(self, binary):
            return hashlib.sha1(binary or b'').hexdigest()
    
        @api.model
        def _get_content_inital_vals(self):
            return {'content_binary': False}
    
        @api.model
        def _update_content_vals(self, file, vals, binary):
            vals.update({
                'checksum': self._get_checksum(binary),
                'size': binary and len(binary) or 0,
            })
            return vals
    
        @api.model
        def _get_binary_max_size(self):
            get_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param
            return int(get_param('muk_web_utils.binary_max_size', default=25))
    
        @api.model
        def _get_forbidden_extensions(self):
            get_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param
            extensions = get_param('muk_dms.forbidden_extensions', default="")
            return [extension.strip() for extension in extensions.split(',')]
    
    
        def _get_thumbnail_placeholder_name(self):
            return self.extension and "file_%s.svg" % self.extension or ""
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Actions
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
    
        def action_migrate(self, logging=True):
            record_count = len(self)
            for index, file in enumerate(self):
                if logging:
                    info = (index + 1, record_count, file.migration)
                    _logger.info(_("Migrate File %s of %s [ %s ]") % info)
                file.with_context(migration=True).write({
                    'content': file.with_context({}).content
                })
    
    
        def action_save_onboarding_file_step(self):
            self.env.user.company_id.set_onboarding_step_done(
                'documents_onboarding_file_state'
            )
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # SearchPanel
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.model
        def _search_panel_directory(self, **kwargs):
            search_domain = kwargs.get('search_domain', []),
            category_domain = kwargs.get('category_domain', [])
            if category_domain and len(category_domain):
                return '=', category_domain[0][2]
            if search_domain and len(search_domain):
                for domain in search_domain[0]:
                    if domain[0] == 'directory':
                        return domain[1], domain[2]
            return None, None
    
        @api.model
        def _search_panel_domain(self, field, operator, directory_id, comodel_domain=[]):
            files_ids = self.search([('directory', operator, directory_id)]).ids
            return expression.AND([comodel_domain, [(field, 'in', files_ids)]])
    
        @api.model
        def search_panel_select_range(self, field_name, **kwargs):
            operator, directory_id = self._search_panel_directory(**kwargs)
            if directory_id and field_name == 'directory':
                domain = expression.AND([
                    kwargs.get('search_domain', []),
                    kwargs.get('category_domain', []),
                    kwargs.get('filter_domain', []),
                    [('parent_directory', operator, directory_id)],
                ])
                values = self.env['muk_dms.directory'].search_read(
                    domain, ['display_name', 'parent_directory']
                )
                return {
                    'parent_field': 'parent_directory',
                    'values': values if len(values) > 1 else [],
                }
            return super(File, self).search_panel_select_range(field_name, **kwargs)
    
        @api.model
        def search_panel_select_multi_range(self, field_name, **kwargs):
            operator, directory_id = self._search_panel_directory(**kwargs)
            if field_name == 'tags':
                sql_query = '''
                    SELECT t.name AS name, t.id AS id, c.name AS group_name,
                        c.id AS group_id, COUNT(r.fid) AS count
                    FROM muk_dms_tag t
                    JOIN muk_dms_category c ON t.category = c.id
                    LEFT JOIN muk_dms_file_tag_rel r ON t.id = r.tid 
                    {directory_where_clause}
                    GROUP BY c.name, c.id, t.name, t.id
                    ORDER BY c.name, c.id, t.name, t.id;
                '''
                where_clause = ''
                if directory_id:
                    directory_where_clause = 'WHERE r.fid = ANY (VALUES {ids})'
                    file_ids = self.search([('directory', operator, directory_id)]).ids
                    where_clause = '' if not file_ids else directory_where_clause.format(
                        ids=', '.join(map(lambda id: '(%s)' % id, file_ids))
                    )
                self.env.cr.execute(sql_query.format(directory_where_clause=where_clause), [])
                return self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
            if directory_id and field_name in ['directory', 'category']:
                comodel_domain = kwargs.pop('comodel_domain', [])
                directory_comodel_domain = self._search_panel_domain(
                    'files', operator, directory_id, comodel_domain
                )
                return super(File, self).search_panel_select_multi_range(
                    field_name, comodel_domain=directory_comodel_domain, **kwargs
                )
            return super(File, self).search_panel_select_multi_range(field_name, **kwargs)
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Read
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.depends('name', 'directory', 'directory.parent_path')
        def _compute_path(self):
            records_with_directory = self - self.filtered(lambda rec: not rec.directory)
            if records_with_directory:
                paths = [list(map(int, rec.directory.parent_path.split('/')[:-1])) for rec in records_with_directory]
                model = self.env['muk_dms.directory'].with_context(dms_directory_show_path=False)
                directories = model.browse(set(functools.reduce(operator.concat, paths)))
                data = dict(directories._filter_access('read').name_get())
                for record in self:
                    path_names = []
                    path_json = []
                    for id in reversed(list(map(int, record.directory.parent_path.split('/')[:-1]))):
                        if id not in data:
                            break
                        path_names.append(data[id])
                        path_json.append({
                            'model': model._name,
                            'name': data[id],
                            'id': id,
                        })
                    path_names.reverse()
                    path_json.reverse()
                    name = record.name_get()
                    path_names.append(name[0][1])
                    path_json.append({
                        'model': record._name,
                        'name': name[0][1],
                        'id': isinstance(record.id, int) and record.id or 0,
                    })
                    record.update({
                        'path_names': '/'.join(path_names),
                        'path_json': json.dumps(path_json),
                    })
    
        # @api.depends('name')
        # def _compute_extension(self):
        #     for record in self:
        #         record.extension = file.guess_extension(record.name)
        @api.depends('name')
        def _compute_mimetype(self):
            for record in self:
                mimetype = record.name and mimetypes.guess_type(record.name)[0]
                if not mimetype:
                    binary = base64.b64decode(record.with_context({}).content or "")
                    mimetype = guess_mimetype(binary, default='application/octet-stream')
                record.mimetype = mimetype
    
        @api.depends('content_binary')
        def _compute_content(self):
            for record in self:
                record.content = record.content_binary
    
        @api.depends('content_binary')
        def _compute_save_type(self):
            for record in self:
                record.save_type = "database"
    
        @api.depends('storage', 'storage.save_type')
        def _compute_migration(self):
            storage_model = self.env['muk_dms.storage']
            save_field = storage_model._fields['save_type']
            values = save_field._description_selection(self.env)
            selection = {value[0]: value[1] for value in values}
            for record in self:
                storage_type = record.storage.save_type
                if storage_type != record.save_type:
                    storage_label = selection.get(storage_type)
                    file_label = selection.get(record.save_type)
                    record.migration = "%s > %s" % (file_label, storage_label)
                else:
                    record.migration = selection.get(storage_type)
    
    
        def read(self, fields=None, load='_classic_read'):
            self.check_directory_access('read', {}, True)
            return super(File, self).read(fields, load=load)
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # View
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.onchange('category')
        def _change_category(self):
            res = {'domain': {
                'tags': [('category', '=', False)]
            }}
            if self.category:
                res.update({'domain': {
                    'tags': ['|',
                        ('category', '=', False),
                        ('category', 'child_of', self.category.id)
                    ]
                }})
            tags = self.tags.filtered(
                lambda rec: not rec.category or \
                rec.category == self.category
            )
            self.tags = tags
            return res
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Security
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.model
        def _get_directories_from_database(self, file_ids):
            if not file_ids:
                return self.env['muk_dms.directory']
            sql_query = '''
                SELECT directory 
                FROM muk_dms_file
                WHERE id = ANY (VALUES {ids});
            '''.format(
                ids=', '.join(map(lambda id: '(%s)' % id, file_ids))
            )
            self.env.cr.execute(sql_query, [])
            result = set(val[0] for val in self.env.cr.fetchall())
            return self.env['muk_dms.directory'].browse(result)
    
        @api.model
        def _read_group_process_groupby(self, gb, query):
            if self.env.user.id == SUPERUSER_ID or isinstance(self.env.uid, NoSecurityUid):
                return super(File, self)._read_group_process_groupby(gb, query)
            directories = self.env['muk_dms.directory'].with_context(prefetch_fields=False).search([])
            if directories:
                where_clause = '"{table}"."{field}" = ANY (VALUES {ids})'.format(
                    table=self._table,
                    field='directory',
                    ids=', '.join(map(lambda id: '(%s)' % id, directories.ids)),
                )
                # query.where_clause += [where_clause]
            else:
                query.where_clause += ['0=1']
            return super(File, self)._read_group_process_groupby(gb, query)
    
        @api.model
        def _search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False, access_rights_uid=None):
            result = super(File, self)._search(args, offset, limit, order, False, access_rights_uid)
            if self.env.user.id == SUPERUSER_ID or isinstance(self.env.uid,NoSecurityUid):
                return len(result) if count else result
            if not result:
                return 0 if count else []
            file_ids = set(result)
            directories = self._get_directories_from_database(result)
            for directory in directories - directories._filter_access('read'):
                file_ids -= set(directory.sudo().mapped('files').ids)
            return len(file_ids) if count else list(file_ids)
    
    
        def _filter_access(self, operation):
            records = super(File, self)._filter_access(operation)
            if self.env.user.id == SUPERUSER_ID or isinstance(self.env.uid, NoSecurityUid):
                return records
            directories = self._get_directories_from_database(records.ids)
            for directory in directories - directories._filter_access('read'):
                records -= self.browse(directory.sudo().mapped('files').ids)
            return records
    
    
        def check_access(self, operation, raise_exception=False):
            res = super(File, self).check_access(operation, raise_exception)
            try:
                return res and self.check_directory_access(operation) == None
            except AccessError:
                if raise_exception:
                    raise
                return False
    
    
        def check_directory_access(self, operation, vals={}, raise_exception=False):
            if self.env.user.id == SUPERUSER_ID or isinstance(self.env.uid, NoSecurityUid):
                return None
            if 'directory' in vals and vals['directory']:
                records = self.env['muk_dms.directory'].browse(vals['directory'])
            else:
                records = self._get_directories_from_database(self.ids)
            return records.check_access(operation, raise_exception)
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Constrains
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
        @api.constrains('name')
        def _check_name(self):
            for record in self:
                files = record.sudo().directory.files.name_get()
                if list(filter(lambda file: file[1] == record.name and file[0] != record.id, files)):
                    raise ValidationError(_("A file with the same name already exists."))
    
        @api.constrains('extension')
        def _check_extension(self):
            for record in self:
                if record.extension and record.extension in self._get_forbidden_extensions():
                    raise ValidationError(_("The file has a forbidden file extension."))
    
        @api.constrains('size')
        def _check_size(self):
            for record in self:
                if record.size and record.size > self._get_binary_max_size() * 1024 * 1024:
                    raise ValidationError(_("The maximum upload size is %s MB).") % self._get_binary_max_size())
    
        @api.constrains('directory')
        def _check_directory_access(self):
            for record in self:
                if not record.directory.check_access('create', raise_exception=False):
                    raise ValidationError(_("The directory has to have the permission to create files."))
    
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        # Create, Update, Delete
        #----------------------------------------------------------
    
    
        def _inverse_content(self):
            updates = defaultdict(set)
            for record in self:
                values = self._get_content_inital_vals()
                binary = base64.b64decode(record.content or "")
                values = self._update_content_vals(record, values, binary)
                values.update({
                    'content_binary': record.content,
                })
                updates[tools.frozendict(values)].add(record.id)
            with self.env.norecompute():
                for vals, ids in updates.items():
                    self.browse(ids).write(dict(vals))
            self.recompute()
    
    
        @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
        def copy(self, default=None):
            self.ensure_one()
            default = dict(default or [])
            names = []
            if 'directory' in default:
                model = self.env['muk_dms.directory']
                directory = model.browse(default['directory'])
                names = directory.sudo().files.mapped('name')
            else:
                names = self.sudo().directory.files.mapped('name')
            default.update({
                'name': file.unique_name(self.name, names, self.extension)
            })
            self.check_directory_access('create', default, True)
            return super(File, self).copy(default)
    
    
        def write(self, vals):
            self.check_directory_access('write', vals, True)
            return super(File, self).write(vals)
    
    
        def unlink(self):
            self.check_directory_access('unlink', {}, True)
            return super(File, self).unlink()
```

when I upgrade a module from odoo 12 to odoo 14 then this error occured. here is my error and my module code. Please anyone help me to find this problem. I dont know where is the problem which code i need to be changed please help me. Value error compute method failed. Which part of my code need to be changed i have no clue about it.

Comment: there is entirely too much code here for anyone to look at, please create a _minimal and reproducible_ example

Comment: Try to follow the OCA tasks to do for [Migration-to-version-13.0](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-13.0#tasks-to-do-in-the-migration) and [Migration-to-version-14.0](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-14.0#tasks-to-do-in-the-migration)

Comment: Odoo raises a `ValueError` because a compute method failed to assign  a value to ``muk_dms.file(1,).actions`` field and there is no `actions` field in the above code. Try to find its compute method and make sure it assigns a value in any case to the field, even if it is a falsy one.

Answer (score 1):

While converting module from version 12 to 14, kindly give for loop to select specific records where ever you used api.multi in version 12. Because this kind of  error will rise when it failed to assign unique value on variable in compute function.
For example,

```
for rec in self:
    if rec.val:
        rec.val = rec.vals
```